# Doctrine 2 multiple mapping inheritance

Tags: inheritance, orm, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I defined a Mapped SuperClass for all my entities with GeoLocation capabilities :

```
<?php
namespace Acme\GeoBundle\Entity;

use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
class Placeable {

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="decimal", scale=7)
*/
protected $loc_latitude;

[...]

}
?>
```

I currently mapped two entities to this superclass.
But, I also want to give this geo-mapping to my User entity, provided by FOSUserBundle. The problem is that this entity already entends the User model from the FOSUserBundle :

```
<?php
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User extends BaseUser {}
?>
```

So my question is : how to give the mapping informations from Placeable to my User Entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have maybe a Location/Address object, inheriting from Placeable, and link Location with User.

PS : This is because you can't inherit from multiple entities in PHP

```
<?php

class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Location", inversedBy="user")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="location_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $location;
}

class Location extends Placeable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="location")
     */
    private $user;
}
```